# Generating coupons and applying them by accessing a link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The code below allows the generation of coupons and their automatic application when the user accesses a link like example.com/cart/?coupon-code=mycupon.Unfortunately, the code generates coupons every time the page is reloaded. I tried to modify the code, but I failed to make it functional.The code should work like this: if a code was generated in a session, another code should not be generated when the page is reloaded. Because I did not find a solution that would not generate another code if one was generated in that session, I tried to make the coupon not be able to be applied together with another code. Unfortunately, I did not manage to make it functional. My code shows that only one coupon was applied to the cart, but in reality all the coupons generated when the page was reloaded were added.Another code change generated almost 7000 coupons for me in a few minutes

The code should generate a different coupon for each user who accesses that link.Can you help me solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

```
function coupon_exists($coupon_code) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND post_name = '%s'", $coupon_code );

    $coupon_codes = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if (count($coupon_codes)> 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} 

// Utility function that generate a non existing coupon code (as each coupon code has to be unique)
function random_coupon_code() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Get an array of all existing coupon codes
    $coupon_codes_check = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon'");
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++ ) {
        $generated_code = strtolower( wp_generate_password( 15, false ) );
        
        // Check if the generated code doesn't exist yet
        if( in_array( $generated_code, $coupon_codes_check ) ) {
            $i--; // continue the loop and generate a new code
        } else {
            break; // stop the loop: The generated coupon code doesn't exist already
        }
    }
    return $generated_code;
}  

function generate_random_coupon($coupon_generated) {
    
// Set some coupon data by default
    $date_expires     = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days'));
    $discount_type    = 'fixed_cart'; // 'store_credit' doesn't exist
    $coupon_amount    = '10';

    $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
    
    // Generate a non existing coupon code name
    $coupon_code  = random_coupon_code();
    $coupon->set_code($coupon_generated);
    //the coupon discount type can be 'fixed_cart', 'percent' or 'fixed_product', defaults to 'fixed_cart'
    $coupon->set_discount_type($discount_type);
    //the discount amount, defaults to zero
    $coupon->set_amount($coupon_amount );
    $coupon->set_date_expires( $date_expires );

    //save the coupon
    $coupon->save();

    return $coupon_generated;
}


function hwn_add_programmatically_created_coupon_to_basket( $cart ) {
    
   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
      return;
   if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
      return;
   $coupon_code  = random_coupon_code();
    
   if (!coupon_exists($coupon_code)) {
      generate_random_coupon($coupon_code);
   }        
   $applied_coupons  = $cart->get_applied_coupons();
   if( ! in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons)){
      $cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
      wc_print_notices();
   }
   elseif( in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons)){
      $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
   }    
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'hwn_add_programmatically_created_coupon_to_basket');
```

Although there is an answer that was accepted on the other post, the solution provided there generates only one coupon and I need one coupon for each user.That's why I decided to ask to find another answer that suits my needs.